# How to direct a html file to process different php files based on if statement

Tags: php, html, post, if-statement

I want to direct my html file based on the condition given by user in the front end (i.e. in the same html file itself).

Like if user enters code 789 it should direct to a specific folder u57.php and if it user enters 783 it should direct to the folder u38.php

i wrote a code, but it doesn't work properly...

```
$a = 57;
$b = 38;
$residue = $_POST["residue"];

<?php if($residue == "$a") { ?>
     <form method="POST" action="u57.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php } ?>

<?php if ($residue == "$b") { ?>
       <form method="POST" action="u38.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php } ?>
```

Its directing to only the same page u57.php, if user enters 38 or any other number like 40, 45, 1 ,2 . Please tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: do you really need want separate php pages? wouldn't sending the  $residue value as an argument be simpler and easier to maintain? as to the errors your checking literal $a not the value due to the quotes

Comment: have you checked the value of $residue??

Comment: var_dump($residue); die(); and see whats in it

Comment: @dragon yes i do want different php files to get accessed.

Comment: you may think you want it, but i doubt its the best option any way the answer is the  quotes on the variables.

Comment: Why do you think the quotes make any difference? Variables are expanded inside double quotes.

Comment: Is the above the actual code copied from the PHP file? If not, make sure the real script uses `==` and not `=` in the if-statements. That's a common typo.

Comment: @Barmar the code is written in php as a part of html code

Comment: I know that. What I wanted to know is if the code in your question is a verbatim copy of the real code. Sometimes there are typos in the original code that don't appear when you rewrite it in SO.

Comment: @user1427429 : Please post the code from where "residue" is posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this Works, (Just removed the Double Quotes for Condition Check)**

```
$a = 57;
$b = 38;
$residue = $_POST["residue"];

<?php if($residue == $a) { ?>
     <form method="POST" action="u57.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php } ?>

<?php if ($residue == $b) { ?>
       <form method="POST" action="u38.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php } ?>
```

- **UPDATE**

Here is the sample i did,

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="redirect.php">
            Value : <input type="text" name="residue" value=""/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**REDIRECT.PHP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $a = 57;
        $b = 38;
        $residue = $_POST["residue"];
        ?>
        <?php if ($residue == $a) {
            ?>
            <form method="POST" action="u57.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" name="sample" value=""/>
            </form>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ($residue == $b) { ?>
```

**This Works for me....**

Comment: @Cole Johnson : Yes, that's perfect.

Comment: @vijay still its moving to the same php file u57.php :(

Comment: There's no difference between `$a` and `"$a"`. Variables are expanded in double-quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the include keyword instead of using the form method and action separately for each and every single pages you have created? Using a switch statement or "if else if' condition might produce you an efficient result I suppose.